# Best examples of data visualisation?

Tags: visualization

I love data visualisation and to spread that love I thought we could share our favourite examples of data visualisation:

**Chess moves** http://turbulence.org/spotlight/thinking/chess.html

**Chris Harrison's Visualisations** http://www.chrisharrison.net/projects/visualization.html

I especially like the bible and Wikipedia visualisations.

---

If you're interested in creating your own visualisations a good place to start would be to check out processing.js (http://ejohn.org/blog/processingjs/).

Answer (score 8):

[glTail.rb](http://www.fudgie.org/) - real time log info, Linux only.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

This is a recent favorite [The Ebb and Flow of Movies: Box Office Receipts 1986 — 2008](http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2008/02/23/movies/20080223_REVENUE_GRAPHIC.html).

Blew my mind is college [Napoleon's Invasion of Russia, 1812](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/29/Minard.png).

And always check out [Tufte](http://www.edwardtufte.com/tufte/index).

Answer (score 6):

I always found [Gource](http://code.google.com/p/gource/) to be pretty interesting; check out some of the samples.  Histories of git projects.

Comment: Related thread [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/138084/how-to-visualise-git-commits-on-a-video-like-a-process).

Answer (score 5):

I find [codeswarm](http://vis.cs.ucdavis.edu/~ogawa/codeswarm/) really amazing. Check out the [video of eclipse](http://www.vimeo.com/1130828).

Answer (score 1):

I just came across the JavaScript lib called Raphael, haven't tried it but the demos impressed me:

http://raphaeljs.com

-- pete

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised no one has suggested d3 yet. Check out the website, its awesome: http://mbostock.github.com/d3/

Answer (score 1):

For a large collection of manually selected information visualizations, please see http://www.infovis.info -- some of the online collections that I drew from no longer exist!

Answer (score 1):

I show or link some examples in my blog post here: http://mycarta.wordpress.com/2011/11/17/time-to-spice-up-your-visualization-skills/

There is also a terrific selection of examples on this thread in Quora:
http://www.quora.com/Data-Visualization/What-are-the-best-data-visualizations-ever-created

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine did this and got it exposed at MOMA in NY

http://pmcruz.com/information-visualization/traffic-in-lisbon-condensed-in-one-day

It represents the trafic in lisbon over time, it was done with processing and there is no map behind it, just the coordinates of cars with public gps moving around